# The best way to store barcodes to import it later to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of barcodes changes every day, and there is no specific count of these barcodes, I want to store them into a file, I thought about excel but the problem that it is changing the value of the barcode.
as example I have a barcode `'4903047158887'` and excel declare it as `'4.90305E+12'` and that won't work, because when I convert it to `CSV` file It copy the same value to CSV.

What is the best file type I should use to effectively imported with PHP to mysql table in specific columns only not rows and is there a PHP code to do this work?

Comment: You can save the barcodes to a CSV file without changing them... If you need to use Excel to view them or something, you can change the formatting.

Comment: Barcodes are just strings. Store them as strings.